# Folders first from RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Tags: php, recursion

I wrote this code a long time ago to get files from a folder structure given in `$dir`.

```
$recursiveIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
$ritit = new RegexIterator($recursiveIterator, $filter);
foreach ($ritit as $splFileInfo) { 
    if(($splFileInfo->getFileName() != ".") && ($splFileInfo->getFileName() != "..")) {
        $path = $splFileInfo->isDir() 
                ? array($splFileInfo->getFilename() => array()) 
                : array($splFileInfo->getFilename()); 
        for ($depth = $ritit->getDepth() - 1; $depth >= 0; $depth--) { 
            $path = array($ritit->getSubIterator($depth)->current()->getFilename() => $path); 
        }
        $return = array_merge_recursive($return, $path);
    }
}
```

And as the title suggests, I want the $return array to have the folders first.  I first attempted to correct this with a `foreach` after the loop, and sort into `$folders` and `$files` array, however this wouldnt change the contents inside the folders, if there were mutliple children inside children.

Is there a way to modify the above loop so that all folders appear first in the array and files after? Including children and children's children?

Comment: Can you show how your output looks like? It's difficult to comprehend what we could get from the code.

Comment: It basically shows an array with keys as the folder names and files below.

Comment: So, key is the folder name and files are it's array values? Can you share a sample input and output?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can modify the loop to get the output array the way you want it. Instead, I'd rather use recursive sorting function to sort the array after the loop.

First, create function that defines the logic for sorting elements. In your case, you want the array-type elements to be the first elements in a tier, so the sorting function could look like this:

```
function dirFirstSorting($a, $b)
{
    if (is_array($a) && is_string($b)) {
        return -1;
    } elseif (is_string($a) && is_array($b)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then, create a function that recursively sorts elements in array:

```
function sortFilesListing(&$array)
{
    if (is_array($array)) {
        uasort($array, "dirFirstSorting");
        array_walk($array, "sortFilesListing");
    }
}
```

All you need to do now, is to call `sortFilesListing` function with `$return` array provided:

```
sortFilesListing($return);
```

The `$return` array elements should be now sorted accordingly.